# Change a channel in select{case:channel}

Tags: go, channel

I use a Ticker to execute tasks periodically, but I've got some problems when changing it. I'll change the ticker to a new one on receiving some messages and change the interval. Here's the sample code which will repro this problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type A struct {
    ticker *time.Ticker
}

func (a *A) modify() {
    a.ticker.Stop()
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
}
func main() {
    a := new(A)
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-a.ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("now")
                go a.modify()
                /*
                    default:
                        //fmt.Println("default")
                        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
                */
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
}
```

"now" will be printed only once. But it will be printed continously if I remove the "go", like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type A struct {
    ticker *time.Ticker
}

func (a *A) modify() {
    a.ticker.Stop()
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
}
func main() {
    a := new(A)
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-a.ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("now")
                a.modify()
                /*
                    default:
                        //fmt.Println("default")
                        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
                */
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)
}
```

Also, if I leave the default clause un-commented, "now" can be printed continously.
Can anyone explain how would this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that goroutine runs asynchronously.
your code behave like this when using `a.modify()`:

1. get tick from `a.ticker.C`
2. stop old ticker, and create new `a.ticker.C`
3. wait for `a.ticker.C` using `select`

In this case, newly created `a.ticker.C` in 2. is identical to channel waiting in 3.

If you do 2. in goroutine. it may be done in following order

1. get tick from `a.ticker.C`
2. wait for `a.ticker.C` using `select`
3. stop old ticker, and create new `a.ticker.C`

In this case channel waiting in 2. is different from newly created channel in 3. .
Since selecting channel is old one which is stopped, it never gets any tick.

You can confirm this behavior inserting some `fmt.Printf` and watch for the address of `a.ticker.C`.

```
func (a *A) modify() {
    a.ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Printf("ticker stopped: %p\n", &a.ticker.C)
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("new ticker created: %p\n", &a.ticker.C)
}
func main() {
    a := new(A)
    a.ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            fmt.Printf("waiting for ticker: %p\n", &a.ticker.C)
            select {
        ....
```

with `a.modify()`:

```
waiting for ticker: 0xc420010100
ticker stopped: 0xc420010100
new ticker created: 0xc420068000
waiting for ticker: 0xc420068000
ticker stopped: 0xc420068000
new ticker created: 0xc420068080
waiting for ticker: 0xc420068080
```

with `go a.modify()`:

```
waiting for ticker: 0xc420010100
waiting for ticker: 0xc420010100
ticker stopped: 0xc420010100
new ticker created: 0xc420066040
```

you can see that with `go a.modify()` you are not waiting for a newly created channel.

**UPDATE for behavior of default:**

When using `default:` with `go a.modify()`, it will behave like this.

1. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got tick, call `go a.modify()` which does 3.
2. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got nothing, so fallback to default and sleep 100ms.
3. stop old ticker, update `a.ticker.C`
4. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got nothing, so fallback to default and sleep 100ms.
5. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got nothing, so fallback to default and sleep 100ms.
6. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got nothing, so fallback to default and sleep 100ms.

.....

7. wait for `a.ticker.C`, got tick, call `go a.modify()`

The point is that `for{}` loop can keep on going even when you got nothing from `a.ticker.C`.
You can confirm the behavior with same code.

```
waiting ticker: 0xc420010100     <-- 1.
now                              <-- 1.
waiting ticker: 0xc420010100     <-- 2.
default                          <-- 2.
ticker stopped: 0xc420010100     <-- 3.
new ticker created: 0xc420066240 <-- 3.
waiting ticker: 0xc420066240     <-- 4.
default                          <-- 4.
```

Comment: Got it! So why the case with default can be explained,too